# Windows Server 2012 R2 HP MFP M130fn driver not installing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, network-printer

I'm having a problem with installing the Windows Server 2012 R2 and the 2008 R2 driver for the HP MFP m130fn LaserJet printer.

What I've tried so far:
I visited [the download center](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-M130-series/9365370/model/9365373), change the registered version and downloaded the appropriate version of the driver.
I tried opening the installer, and after extracting I get the error "The operating system is not supported".

The driver that is currently installed is broken and keeps crashing the printer spooler service, so I would very much like this fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to manually update the driver for the printer. After extracting navigate to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\ and find the folder with similar name 7zS5081 (for example). Inside the folder, you can find the drivers.

Open Device Manager, right click existing printer device and select update the firmware. Choose to update it manually and "From Disk". Specify the folder which you have found previously and you will see LaserJet M129 PCL driver. Select one of them and test it.

Comment: Thanks for that :)  
This didn't fix it for me, but it's a good trick to know.